# Error executing query on UNIX SQL Console

Tags: sql, oracle, unix

I am trying to execute a query using UNIX SQL CONSOLE but i am getting error  `"quoted string not properly terminated"` .The same query when executed from SQL developer is running fine .Can you please help on that

```
select name, extract(xmltype(columnname),
       '/Attributes/Map/entry[@key="applications"]/@value')  
from TABLE NAME
```

Comment: Have you tried escaping the quotes using a "\" character?  Something like:`'/Attributes/Map/entry[@key=\"applications\"]/@value')`

Comment: Does the issue affect all quoted strings, or only XML expressions? Is "UNIX SQL CONSOLE" sqlplus on some Linux server, or something else?